# CodeIgniter - Condition - Email Sending Else If

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, if-statement

Lang variable already working in whole web if user lang=en so display a english web otherwise default is arabic, so now i need to set on thing when user submit the data so send email to user but if lang=en so send english image otherwise arabic img or msg whatever we set, i share my code please suggest the mistake.

```
public function sendUserMail($mail, $lang) {
    $this->email->from('noreply@giftotravel.pk', 'Halalat');
    $this->email->to($mail); 
    $this->email->subject('Halalat Newsletter Subscription');
    $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
    if ($lang == "en") {
        $this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/en/bg_en2.jpg" />');   
    } else {
        $this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/ar/bg_ar3.jpg" />');   
    }
    //$this->email->attach('/home/content/f/a/h/fahadghafoor/html/fahad/assests/images/en/bg_en2.jpg');//attachement testing done
    $this->email->send();
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
}
```

Comment: closing tag for img ??

Comment: Already Mention There!

Comment: there is no `</img>` and what is the mail mime type did you set it as html?

Answer (score 2):

If you send HTML email you must send it as a complete web page. also set mailtype variable for email class. and you don't want a closing tag for image tag

```
$this->email->mailtype('html');
```

Images are not technically inserted into an HTML page, images are linked to HTML pages. The  tag creates a holding space for the referenced image.

Comment: $this->email->set_mailtype("html"); is right i think. in my codes $this->email->mailtype('html'); will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function public function sendUserMail($mail, $lang)  {
            $this->email->from('noreply@giftotravel.pk', 'Halalat');
            $this->email->to($mail); 
            $this->email->subject('Halalat Newsletter Subscription');
            if ($lang == "en") {
            $this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/en/bg_en2.jpg"/>');   
            }
            else 
            {
            $this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/ar/bg_ar3.jpg"/>');   
            }

                $this->email->set_mailtype('html');
                $this->email->send();
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
```

Comment: i think you not understand i need to manage to images manipulation only on language input if get input en send email with english image or ar to send arabic but when i fill up the form so it directly go to arabic image line and send arabic image again & again

Comment: can you echo the $lang in that function.And check the value

Comment: if i need to call in message view page from view so its possible remove the image and add view as per our custom html page?

Answer (score 1):

There is no closing tag for img. You should use as below:

```
if ($lang == "en") {
    $this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/en/bg_en2.jpg"/>');   
} else {
    $this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/ar/bg_ar3.jpg"/>');   
}
```

Comment: i already pass the variable $lang but still else condition not work

Comment: just check what your are receiving?

Comment: one problem new i found, when fill up form in arabic so it shows send arabic image but email not recvd.

Answer (score 0):

change your image tags:

```
$this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/en/bg_en2.jpg" />');   

$this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/ar/bg_ar3.jpg" />');
```

also set:

```
$this->email->set_mailtype("html");
```

for emailing html contents.

change function to:

```
public function sendUserMail($mail, $lang='en')
```

by default it takes **'en'**

Comment: set an initial value for $lang if no value came from response.

Comment: add $lang=NULL; in the first line

Answer (score 0):

i fix the error in code in function i miss the $lang update code here

```
public function sendUserMail($mail) {
            $lang = $this->input->post("lang");
            $this->email->from('noreply@giftotravel.pk', 'Halalat');
            $this->email->to($mail); 
            $this->email->subject('Halalat Newsletter Subscription');
            $this->email->set_mailtype("html");
             if ($lang == "en") {
            $this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/en/bg_en2.jpg" />');   
            }
            else 
            {
            $this->email->message('<img src="http://fahad.myradio.pk/assests/images/ar/bg_ar3.jpg" />');   
            }
            //$this->email->attach('/home/content/f/a/h/fahadghafoor/html/fahad/assests/images/en/bg_en2.jpg');//attachement testing done
            $this->email->send();
            echo $this->email->print_debugger();
        }
```

Thanks to Adarsh & kumar_v